# How to embed a Linux command-line like editor into a Qt app?

Tags: qt

There's a cool guitar tabbing application that I've used before where you can use the keyboard to move around a character grid. You can put any digit in any character cell.  Here is an image:

[image]

In effect, **it works just like the Linux console** where you have a cursor block and you can move around character by character.

I am using Qt as my GUI application. How would I go about adding this type of single-character editor control in my application? I have not run across this type of widget in any of my exposure to GUI programming; hence, I'm not even sure what to call it or how to describe it succinctly.

Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, would be tempting to try and use a QPlainTextEdit with some sort of underlay. You'd get a lot for free like undo/redo. Not sure if that'd work/be possible. Just an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you would have to implement handlers for each key you would like to respond to when pressed/release/hold.

The widget implementation would be like implementing a Finite State Machine with states like `Navigating` and `Editing` and so on.

For each key pressed you would act accordingly to update your widget or perform another action, including change the state of the widget.

In a high level form, this would be like:

```
void MyCrazyWidget::on_keyDown(QKeyEvent event) {
    switch ( this->state() ) {
        case State::Navigating:
            this->navigatingStateHandleKeyDown(event);
            break;
        case State::Editing:
            this->editingStateHandleKeyDown(event);
            break;
        default:
            // waaaat???
    }
}

void MyCrazyWidget::navigatingStateHandleKeyDown(QKeyEvent event) {
    switch ( event.key() ) {
        // handle each of the keys here (or simply ignore those without an action).
    }
}

void MyCrazyWidget::editingStateHandleKeyDown(QKeyEvent event) {
    switch ( event.key() ) {
        // handle each of the keys here (or simply ignore those without an action).
    }
}
```

This is obviously very high level, but is pretty much these things are handled (afaik). It's a boring and hard job, but we really need our editors ;D